# How to show 50×50 image thumbnail in Related Post

Tags: php

I am showing related post in my WordPress without any plugin, the issue is I want to show custom size of image in related post via CSS, how to do this?

Here is my related post code .

```
<?php endwhile; endif; ?>
<?php $orig_post = $post;
global $post;
$categories = get_the_category($post->ID);
if ($categories) {
$category_ids = array();
foreach($categories as $individual_category) $category_ids[] = $individual_category->term_id;
$args=array(
'category__in' => $category_ids,
'post__not_in' => array($post->ID),
'posts_per_page'=> 8, // Number of related posts that will be shown.
'caller_get_posts'=>1
);
$my_query = new wp_query( $args );
if( $my_query->have_posts() ) {
echo '<div id="related_posts"><h3>Related Posts</h3><ul>';
while( $my_query->have_posts() ) {
$my_query->the_post();?>
<li><div class="relatedthumb"><a href="<? the_permalink()?>" rel="bookmark" title="<?php the_title(); ?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?></a></div>
<div class="relatedcontent">
<h3><a href="<? the_permalink()?>" rel="bookmark" title="<?php the_title(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h3>
<p>Last updated: <?php the_modified_date(); ?></p>
</div>
</li>
<?
}
echo '</ul></div>';
}
}
$post = $orig_post;
wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change:

```
the_post_thumbnail()
```

To:

```
the_post_thumbnail( array(50, 50) );
```

It's all documented on the codex / developer site at https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/the_post_thumbnail/

Comment: Thank its worked perfect, now I want to give a style like, want to show thumbnail left side on the widget, how to do this